# Discord.js V14 Slash Command Channel Option Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to use the `SlashCommandBuilder` for a **discord.js V14** command but I can't get it to select only **text type channels**.

My current code is below:

```js
const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setup')
        .setDescription('Setup the embed.')
        .addChannelOption(option => option
            .setName('channel')
            .setDescription('text channel')
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .toJSON(),
];
```

I ran it and it works except that it offers me **all** the channel categories, vocals, and text whereas I only wanted the text channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`addChannelTypes()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandChannelOption?scrollTo=addChannelTypes) method to filter what types you want to show. It accepts a list of channel types. The following should work:

```js
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

// ...

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setup')
        .setDescription('Setup the embed.')
        .addChannelOption(option => option
            .setName('channel')
            .setDescription('text channel')
            .addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .toJSON(),
];
```

If you want to accept more than one type, you can simply list them like this:

```js
.addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText, ChannelType.GuildVoice)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I just changed something in your code here is the code I used is this one works const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setup')
        .setDescription('Setup the embed.')
        .addChannelOption(option => option
            .setName('channel')
            .setDescription('text channel')
            .addChannelTypes(ChannelType.GuildText)
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .toJSON(),
];

you just need to remove the [] that you give.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I've fixed that in my answer. Thank you